# Restoring Unicode Character Map facility on Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, 17.04, unicode, special-characters

On Unity-based Ubuntu, I could bring up the Character Map quickly from the Text Entry menu:

[image: character map in Text Entry menu, Ubuntu (Unity) 17.04]

How might I restore similar functionality under Ubuntu Gnome? I use a lot of Unicode characters, and it wouldn't be practical to set up XCompose sequences for all of them.

Comment: You could still do Super > Character map

Comment: I *could*, but that requires me to type Logo Key + 'ch' + Enter, which is kind of convoluted

Comment: - Assign a hotkey for instant keyboard access; - add launcher to favourites for quick mouse access

Answer (score 0):

I've just upgraded Ubuntu from 16 to 18, and had the same issue. After installing **gucharmap** that functionality was restored. (I find the new character map a cute complement, but not a replacement.)

Comment: Thanks, but that menu is long gone from Ubuntu 19